# database update using ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Why this does't work?

```
<form id='formprofile' autocomplete='off'>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo $row['name'];?>'>
    <input type='text' name='sname' value='<?php echo $row['sname'];?>'>
    <button type='button' id='btnsave'>Save</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#btnsave').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'profilesave.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#formprofile').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        if (data =='empty'){
            alert ('something is missing!');
        }
        else{
            alert ('profile saved');
            location.href = 'index.php';
        }
    }
  });
});
```

**profilesave.php**

```
extract($_POST);

if ($name == ''){
    echo ('empty');
    exit();
}

try {
   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET name = :name, sname = :sname WHERE user = :"' . $user . '"');
   $stmt->execute(array(
    ":name" => $name,
    ":sname" => $sname
   ));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Database is not updated.
Variable `$user` is tested, it exists and have a propper value.

Database is not updated.
Variable `$user` is tested, it exists and have a propper value.

Comment: `WHERE user = :"' . $user . '"` ?? why do that and not have that as a named parameter as with `:name` and `:sname`??

Comment: Where is the variable `$user` coming from in the `profilesave.php` script?

Comment: @RamRaider, it's comming from another included file at the top of code. it's tested, it exists and have a propper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is probably more content of `profilesave.php` ( ie: the database include and other variables such as `$user` ) then you should probably construct the prepared statement like this rather than embedding the value directly. You can test if the statement is created successfully before trying to execute it.

```
try{

    $name = !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ? $_POST['name'] : false;
    $sname = !empty( $_POST['sname'] ) ? $_POST['sname'] : false;

    if( $name && $sname ){
        $stmt = $db->prepare( 'UPDATE members SET name = :name, sname = :sname WHERE user = :user' );
        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->execute( array(
                    ':name'     =>  $name,
                    ':sname'    =>  $sname,
                    ':user'     =>  $user
                )
            );
        } else {
            echo 'Prepared statement failed';
        }
    }
} catch( PDOException $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but... what is the mistake in my code ? It should be correct.

Comment: Not quite - your final sql would look something like `UPDATE members SET name = :name, sname = :sname WHERE user = :"Fred"` ~ assuming the $user is Fred - Note the leading colon before Fred!

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot.